# How to speed up AWS RDS snapshot copy with encryption (postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, snapshot

Making a copy of a PostgreSQL (12.3) AWS RDS snapshot to add encryption in the US East region for a 100G DB storage size snapshot takes between 2+ and 4+ hours to complete.

Is there any technique to speed up the copy of a RDS PosgtgreSQL snapshot when adding encryption or otherwise?